# How to save video file to public path folder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

how can I save an uploaded video to the public path? I usually deal with Images and use the Image Intervention Package which only works for images so I don't know how to possibly save a video.
Here's what I tried (doesn't work):

```
$video = $request->file('video');
$vid_name = hexdec(uniqid()) . '.' . $video->getClientOriginalExtension();
Image::make($video)->save('uploads/about/experience_us/' . $vid_name);
$vid_url = 'uploads/about/experience_us/' . $vid_name;

ExperienceUs::updateOrCreate([
    'video' => $vid_url,
]);
```

The `save()` method comes with the Image Intervention as stores the file in the public path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$video = $request->file('video');
$vid_name = hexdec(uniqid()) . '.' . $video->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->move(public_path('uploads/about/experience_us/' ), $vid_name); // changed line
$vid_url = 'uploads/about/experience_us/' . $vid_name;

    ExperienceUs::updateOrCreate([

        'video' => $vid_url,

    ]);
```

i hope it was useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$vid_url = 'uploads/about/experience_us/' . $vid_name;
\Storage::disk('public')->put($vid_url , file_get_content($video));
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The Request went through but no errors. also the file wasn't uplaoded

Comment: check ```config/filesystem.php``` and config public filesystem. this work